# out of memory error: Java heap space

Tags: geoserver, java, image-pyramids

I have installed GeoServer 2.5.5 on Win 7. When I try to view a raster pyramid I see this message:

> OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space.

I google it, but it wasn't useful because I don't use Tomcat and it was no wrapper.conf in my PC.
How can I increase Java heap space?

Comment: If you still have Windows 7 it is possible that you also use a 32-bit version of Java that limits the memory to 2 GB.  GeoServer 2.5 is pretty old, current one is 2.18, but java related things have not changes so much. You can add java options into the startup.bat script that starts GeoServer. But if you run out of memory it is also possible that you have not prepared your data right.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 64bit you can set `JAVA_OPTS` as a system variable and define larger heap size like explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269958/how-to-increase-java-heap-size-on-geoserver-on-windows/269961)

If you are on 32bit windows or installed the 32bit version of Geoserver it seems like you would have to change your installation or use a different OS.
[How to increase Java heap size on GeoServer on Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269958/how-to-increase-java-heap-size-on-geoserver-on-windows/269961)